# Configuring Retry strategy with Amazon S3 client

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When instantiating an Amazon S3 client, one of the constructors accepts instance of class AmazonS3Config. This class can be created as follows:

```
new AmazonS3Config { RetryMode = RequestRetryMode.Standard, MaxErrorRetry = 5 }
```

What exactly are RetryMode values

```
public enum RequestRetryMode
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Legacy request retry strategy.
    Legacy = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Standardized request retry strategy that is consistent across all SDKs.
    Standard = 1,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     An experimental request retry strategy that builds on the Standard strategy and
    //     introduces congestion control through client side rate limiting.
    Adaptive = 2
}
```

and how can they be used for implementing exponential backoff retry?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-retries.html https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/retries.html

Comment: For some reason, I couldn't find this detailed explanation. Only found a page with obscure information. Thank you!